# Decimal com ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho um projeto ASP.NET Core 2.2 com a seguinte configuração na classe Startup

```
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        var supportedCultures = new[] { cultureInfo };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
```

O model possui as seguintes TAGs

```
    [DisplayName("Valor")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Quando faço um post o sistema não reconhece a vírgula como separador de decimal.

O que preciso acrescentar para solucionar o problema?

Comment: Observação, decimal não é o tipo adequando para trabalhar com valores monetários, eu usaria `double`... Como esse dado está vindo da interface?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, o ideal para valore monetários é o decimal mesmo. Por que double, poderia explicar?